# Unable to draw rectangles to select files on desktop

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments

22.04.2 lts

When I try to rightclick my desktop this menu comes up:
[image]

Instead something like this should come up:
"New Folder"
"Paste"
"Select all"
"Arrange Icons"
"Arrange by"
"Show Desktop in files"
"Open in terminal"
"Desktop icon settings"
"Display settings"

Also: I cant draw those rectangles to select files anymore, only in the file manager but not in the desktop.

Comment: With nothing highlighted this is the correct display. The first 2 you list come if you are in the files app. Paste only comes up with a cut action first again in the files app. You scrren shot shows no icons so again this is the correct info.

Comment: Are you using other then the default DE?

Comment: David, I want to clarify. 

on laptop 1 (good) the menu is: 
new folder
paste (grayed out)
select all 
arrange icons
arrange by

etc.

How can I bring that menu back?

Comment: No idea you must have changed something. Like I all ready asked have you done something with the DE? Maybe used something like Gnome Tweaks?

Comment: I experience this in my openSUSE machine and not in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Yes i used gnome tweaks, but only increased the font ==> "zoom factor" to 1.4. I tried resetting my gnome settings but the problem persists!